# can't see all columns after implementing df.isna().sum()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning

I am working on a dataset on jupyter notebook that has 2000 rows and many columns.
I wanna see how many missing items are in each columns
Code:
import pandas as pd
fifa = pd.read_csv('fifa21_raw_data.csv', low_memory = False)
missing =fifa.isna().sum()

But in the result I can see first and last few colums with the count of missing values. But can't see the middle ones in the shell.look at the image...[jupyter notebook result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyrgz.png)
I tried using

pd.options.display.max_columns = None
but it only works for dataframe. not the result of isna().sum()

pd.options.display.max_columns = None

I did it but works on dataframe. I know how to show all columns or rows in the dataframe. but i want this on statistics results like the pic. I wanna see all columns with the number of missing datas